# How to declare MenuItem objects instead of calling it everytime

Tags: android, menu

I don't know how to declare MenuItem object and i call on every method the MenuItem so my code look like:

```
  private Menu menu;
private void updateMenuIconForWifi(){
        MenuItem menuB = menu.findItem(R.id.action_bluetooth);
        MenuItem menuItemW = menu.findItem(R.id.action_wifi);
        menuB.setVisible(false);
        menuItemW.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_network_wifi_black_24dp);
    }

    private void changeIconToDefaultWifi(){
        MenuItem menuB = menu.findItem(R.id.action_bluetooth);
        MenuItem menuItemW = menu.findItem(R.id.action_wifi);
        menuB.setVisible(true);
        menuItemW.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_wifi_white_24dp);
    }

    private void updateMenuIconForBluetooth() {
        MenuItem menuB = menu.findItem(R.id.action_bluetooth);
        MenuItem menuItemW = menu.findItem(R.id.action_wifi);
        menuItemW.setVisible(false);
        menuB.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_bluetooth_connected_black_24dp);
    }

    private void changeIconToDefaultForBluetooth() {
        MenuItem menuB = menu.findItem(R.id.action_bluetooth);
        MenuItem menuItemW = menu.findItem(R.id.action_wifi);
        menuB.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_bluetooth_white_24dp);
        menuItemW.setVisible(true);
    }

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        this.menu = menu;
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_settings, menu);
        for (int j = 0; j < menu.size(); j++) {
            MenuItem item = menu.getItem(j);
            item.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

but this look so ugly.

How to declare the MenuItems once? when i try adding some value like

```
private MenuItem menuB, menuItemW;
```

and then call this like in `onCreate`

```
menuB = menu.findItem(R.id.action_bluetooth);
menuItemW = menu.findItem(R.id.action_wifi);
```

i got a error

Comment: You should use `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`. instead of changing item icon and action on menu.

Comment: good to know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read about [onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29)

Each time the user presses the <kbd>Menu</kbd> on their Android device while inside one of your activities, the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method is called.  The first time the menu is shown (i.e. *only once*), the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method is called.

Basically, the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method is where you should make any changes such as enabling/disabling certain menu items, or changing the menu item text depending on the circumstances.

So do this (Don't use `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` )

```
//Dynamically create context Menu
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.clear(); //Clear view of previous menu
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        if(condition_true)
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_one, menu);
        else
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_two, menu);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can save your menuItem once during onCreateOptionsMenu, and access it subsequently.

```
private MenuItem menuB, menuItemW;


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_settings, menu);

    menuB = menu.findItem(R.id.action_bluetooth);
    menuItemW = menu.findItem(R.id.action_wifi);


    //the rest of your codes
    return true;
}
```